# If $A \in \Bbb{R}^n$ can we write $A^T \in \Bbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

I had a doubt regarding notation if $A$ is an $n \times 1$ column vector taking values from reals then we write $A \in \Bbb{R}^n$ but $A^T$ is a $1 \times n$ row vector taking values in reals. In that case, how are we supposed to write this notationally? Is it okay to write $A^T \in \Bbb{R}^n$  even for $A^T$

Comment: The space of row vectors is very closely related to the space of column vectors is very closely related to the space of $n$-tuples... there is an obvious isomorphism between each... but they are technically distinct spaces as far as rigorous mathematical objects.  If you want to be formal, the first should have been an element of $\Bbb R^{n\times 1}$ while the other is an element of $\Bbb R^{1\times n}$.  That said, because of how similar the spaces themselves are, we might choose to notate either as $\Bbb R^n$ and let context dictate whether we actually mean one or the other.

Comment: If we are working in a context where it is important to tell the difference between row vectors and column vectors, then we should not notate both spaces as the same.  If we are only ever working with one or the other, then it doesn't matter as much to us to be perfectly precise.  Note that a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$ is very closely related to a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^{n\times 1}$ to $\Bbb R^{m\times 1}$ or from $\Bbb R^{1\times n}$ to $\Bbb R^{1\times m}$.  Since the underlying theory works the same regardless which, we don't care that much.

Comment: Formally it is written as $A^{T} \in R^{1 \times n}$, but a lot of times people (that I know) just write $pA$, for example.

Comment: It is a common convention to assert that $\Bbb R^n$ is "the same thing" as $\Bbb R^{n \times 1}$, but $\Bbb R^{n \times 1}$ and $\Bbb R^{1 \times n}$ are distinct. So no, it is not okay to say that $A^T \in \Bbb R^n$. Typically, we say that $A \in \Bbb R^n$ and $A^T \in \Bbb R^{1 \times n}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes you're right I knew that an $m \times n$ matrix is written as being $ \in \Bbb{R}^{m \times n}$ but this didn't come to me; apologize for being so silly 

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes what does $pA$ even mean??? It doesn't even relate to my distant notions 

Comment: @BenGrossmann Truly said

Comment: @RyukendoDey where $p \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. The multiplication $p^{T}A$ is what I meant, but often people write $pA$, which is "okay" until some degree of formality is required.

Comment: Nobody has said that $A^T$ can be identified with an element of the dual space $(\mathbb{R^n})^*$